# Making a certain listView sub-item column editable

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I've found plenty of great information (including this solution) to make a listView column editable. However, I can't find much information on how to lock some functionality to a specific column of sub-items and have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

Please consider the code below:

```
    // Make ListView Editable
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem SelectedLSI;
    private void DwgList_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo i = DwgList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        SelectedLSI = i.SubItem;
        if (SelectedLSI == null)
            return;

        int border = 0;
        switch (DwgList.BorderStyle)
        {
            case BorderStyle.FixedSingle:
                border = 1;
                break;
            case BorderStyle.Fixed3D:
                border = 2;
                break;
        }

        int CellWidth = SelectedLSI.Bounds.Width;
        int CellHeight = SelectedLSI.Bounds.Height;
        int CellLeft = border + DwgList.Left + i.SubItem.Bounds.Left;
        int CellTop = DwgList.Top + i.SubItem.Bounds.Top;

        TxtEdit.Location = new Point(CellLeft, CellTop);
        TxtEdit.Size = new Size(CellWidth, CellHeight);
        TxtEdit.Visible = true;
        TxtEdit.BringToFront();
        TxtEdit.Text = i.SubItem.Text;
        TxtEdit.Select();
        TxtEdit.SelectAll();
    }
    private void DwgList_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HideTextEditor();
    }
    private void DwgList_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HideTextEditor();
    }
    private void TxtEdit_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HideTextEditor();
    }
    private void TxtEdit_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            HideTextEditor();
    }
    private void HideTextEditor()
    {
        TxtEdit.Visible = false;
        if (SelectedLSI != null)
            SelectedLSI.Text = TxtEdit.Text;
        SelectedLSI = null;
        TxtEdit.Text = "";
    }
```

I have tried the following, which produced errors and unpredictable results:

```
    private void DwgList_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo i = DwgList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        SelectedLSI = i.SubItem;
        // Lock to fourth column
        if (i.SubItem == i.Item.SubItems[3])
        {
            ... rest of code here
        }
    }

    private void HideTextEditor()
    {
        if (i.SubItem == i.Item.SubItems[3])
        {
            TxtEdit.Visible = false;
            if (SelectedLSI != null)
                SelectedLSI.Text = TxtEdit.Text;
            SelectedLSI = null;
            TxtEdit.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Please see images below for visual explanations.

I am able to edit columns with my code as shown below:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

But I'm able to edit any columns, I want to lock this functionality to column 4 (subItem 3 for each item) shown in Image 1.

Comment: Only one, namely the 1st, main column can be edited. But you can re-order the columns as needed. - And then there are workarounds..

Comment: Yes, this is a work-around. It allows all columns to be edited using a hidden text box. I want to limit functionality to the 4th column only, though (subitem 3)

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms, ASP, Net, or something else.  Please tag questions in a useful way.

Comment: I expect you will be much better to use one if the many 3rd party grid control then try to get a ListView to do complex staff.    (Showing a text box on mouse down in the correct location etc would work, but take a long time to get looking right.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview%20winforms?sort=Newest&edited=true may help

Comment: All, this is a NET program. Just to clarify, I already have the functionality of editing any data within the listView. However, I want to limit that functionality only to items in the fourth column of my listView (typically subItem 3).

Comment: Please see my edit in regards to this discussion

Comment: As I wrote you can do this easily without any workarounds. Simply make the 1st item display as 4th ! (`columnHeader1.DisplayIndex = 3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you really don't what column you are in. I can think of a couple of ways to solve this:

1) Implement the code from this article to get the column number and test that: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/find-the-listview-row-and-column-under-the-mouse-in-c/

2) Set the subitem tag to true or false to determine edit-ability, then check the tag on the hit test:

```
var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { "i123", "Joe", "55" });

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
       item1.SubItems[i].Tag = true;
    else
       item1.SubItems[i].Tag = false;
}
```

Then for hit test:

```
if (SelectedLSI == null || (bool)SelectedLSI.Tag == false)
   return;
```

I like the subitem tag method myself...

Comment: Kevin, thank you very much for this suggestion. I just learned about the subItem tags :)

Comment: Glad it helped!